# Is there any vscode extension that find variable name with wrong case?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am often writing variable names wrong case which i find after execution.
Like i declared `testId` as a variable but later use it as `testid` . (in Id i is small)

I think it is a common mistake, Is there any extension to find it?

Answer (score 1):

many linters will flag this for you (`variable used before set`).

If the language is case sensitive they are different variables and thus legal.

Use the intellisense of VSC to only select variables that are defined. It works for Python, C++, JavaScript.

VSC for some languages shows squiggles on variables `not used` or `not defined`